# Using string from context outside of context

Tags: java, android

I'm quite new to android studio and java in general, so this might seem like a stupid question, but anyways here it goes:

I have a SQLiteOpenHelper class called "database" (that I use to do all sorts of database stuff) and I want to get a string from strings.xml.

Here is my context:

```
public database(Context context) {
    super(context,
            DB_NAME_CORE + context.getResources().getString(R.string.db_version),
            null,
            context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.db_version_int));
    String db_version = context.getResources().getString(R.string.db_version);
    this.context = context;
}
```

With this I can get the string i want (db_version), but I can't figure out how to use it outside "context" or "onCreate"..

So; how can I use the String "db_version" outside of context/onCreate?

Is it possible somehow? Or not? I don't know..

Comment: Whoa.  Are you storing a reference to a Context in a helper class that retains that reference?  You will have memory leaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would argue storing the database version number in a strings.xml file is not ideal.  It would be much better to simply create a private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = n; directly in your helper class.

That way you don't have a weird dependency on a string resource file in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

That `getString()` method is [part of the Context class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int)). So, whenever you want to call an xml resource via `getString()`, you will have to pass a context.

If you really can't/don't want to pass/use a context, you either should save in a [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or as a Java constant.